# Rails AJAX Update on Select

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have an Index view that lists orders in a collection. Each order has a status. I want to be able to update the status of an order from the Index page, AJAX style.

Not sure why the ID is NULL when trying to update the record.

index.html.erb

```
<h1>Recent Orders</h1>

<section class="order-results">
  <ol class="list-group">
    <%= render partial: 'pf_order', collection: @pf_orders %>
  </ol>
</section>
```

_pf_orders.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(pf_order, url: update_receiver_status_path(pf_order)) do |f| %>
    <%= f.select :receiver_status, options_for_select(receiver_statuses, f.object.receiver_status), {include_blank: true}, {class: 'form-control'} %>
<% end %>
```

pf_orders_controller.rb

```
def index
  @pf_orders = PfOrder.all
end

def update_receiver_status
  @status = PfOrder.find_by(id: params[:id])
  @status.update_attributes(pf_order_params)
end
```

pf_orders.coffee

```
jQuery ($) ->
  $(document).ready ->
    $("#pf_order_receiver_status").bind 'change', ->
      $.ajax
        type: 'PATCH'
        url: 'pf_orders/update_receiver_status'
        data: 'pf_order[receiver_status]=' + $('#pf_order_receiver_status').val()
```

routes.rb

```
patch 'pf_orders/update_receiver_status', as: 'update_receiver_status'
```

LOGS

```
Started PATCH "/pf_orders/update_receiver_status" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-10-01 17:36:11 -0400
Processing by PfOrdersController#update_receiver_status as */*
  Parameters: {"pf_order"=>{"receiver_status"=>"Completed"}}
  PfOrder Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "pf_orders".* FROM "pf_orders" WHERE "pf_orders"."id" IS NULL LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)



NoMethodError (undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I got this to work correctly:

pf_orders_controller.rb

```
def update_receiver_status
  @pf_order = PfOrder.find(params[:id])
  if @pf_order.update_attributes(pf_order_params)
    render json: @pf_order.as_json, status: :ok
  else
    render json: {pf_order: @pf_order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
  end
end

def pf_order_params
  params.fetch(:pf_order, {}).permit(:sequence_number, :message_guid, :hl7_document, :download, :post_status_code, :patient_id, :receiver_status)
end
```

_pf_order.html.erb

Got rid of the `form_for`

```
<%= label :receiver_status, 'Status:' %>
          <%= select_tag :receiver_status,
                         options_for_select(receiver_statuses, pf_order[:receiver_status]),
                         onchange: "$.post('#{update_receiver_status_pf_order_path(pf_order)}',
                         {'_method':'patch', 'pf_order[receiver_status]':this.value} );",
                         class: 'form-control' %>
```

I removed the jQuery from `pf_orders.coffee`

routes.rb

```
resources :pf_orders do
  patch :update_receiver_status, on: :member
end
```

Thanks to Alexandre Angelim for the correct route and pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You're not submitting the order's id anywhere. You can verify that in your logs
`Parameters: {"pf_order"=>{"receiver_status"=>"Completed"}}`.

If you'd like to stick with RESTful routes(and I strongly believe you should), you're request should go to `/pf_orders/:id/update_receiver_status`.

You can change your route to:

```
patch 'pf_orders/:id/update_receiver_status', as: 'update_receiver_status'
```

or just add a custom route to your pf_orders resources:

```
resources :pf_orders do
  patch :update_receiver_status, on: :member
end
```

The last thing to do is retrieve the order's id in your javascript. That will already be reflected in your form's action URL, so it's easier to retrieve it from there.

```
jQuery ($) ->
  $(document).ready ->
    $("#pf_order_receiver_status").bind 'change', ->
      $.ajax
        type: 'PATCH'
        url: $('#pf_order_receiver_status').closest('form').attr('action')
        data: 'pf_order[receiver_status]=' + $('#pf_order_receiver_status').val()
```

Comment: Made the changes but now I'm getting: 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PATCH] "/pf_orders"):

Comment: try `form_for(pf_order, url: update_receiver_status_pf_order_path(pf_order))`

Comment: Here's my PATCH route from rake routes: 
`update_receiver_status_pf_order PATCH  /pf_orders/:id/update_receiver_status(.:format) pf_orders#update_receiver_status`

Comment: Are you sure you have an order already when you got to that page or are you creating an order there? It looks like `form_for` is generating the wrong path.

Comment: Looks like that variable `pf_order` is nil, so the helper is using the current path as the action url.

Comment: The problem seems to be that I'm trying to use a form_for in a collection. What would be the alternative to doing this AJAX style?

Comment: The variable `pf_order` is a collection? Isn't it an instance of `PfOrder`?

Comment: I've added my index action and index view to my original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124807/discussion-between-alexandre-angelim-and-bradbajuz).